# how to temporarily block scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrolltop, preventdefault

I'm trying to reproduce the following effect: http://tympanus.net/Development/ArticleIntroEffects/ and i got this far: http://codepen.io/vlrprbttst/pen/LGMVyj

the only difference with the demo is the scroll managing. on my example, if you scroll too much, you'll find yourself scrolled too far in the page. and that's something i want to prevent. in the codrops example instead, it looks like the scrolling is temporarily blocked, and is renabled once the animation of the disappearing header is finished.

i tried this:

```
function intro() {
  var wh = window.innerHeight;
  $(".header").css("height", wh);
  $(".subsection").css("padding-top", (wh / 3 * 2));

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var header = $(".header");
    var subsection = $(".subsection");
    if (scroll >= 1) {
      header.addClass("header--scrolled");
      subsection.addClass("header--scrolled");
      $("body").css("overflow","hidden");
      header.one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',
        function(e) {
        $("body").css("overflow","scroll");
        });
    } else {
      $(".subsection").removeClass("header--scrolled");
      $(".header").removeClass("header--scrolled");
    }
  });
};
intro();
```

so basically if you scroll +1 pixel, you get `$("body").css("overflow","hidden");`and once the transition is done, you go back to `$("body").css("overflow","scroll");`

but this is not working.
any idea on how I can do this?

Comment: To block scrolling, this plugin uses `window.scrollTo( 0, 0 );` when user attempts to scroll and animation is still running

Comment: @A.Wolff i was hoping to reproducing it without copying

Comment: Ya but issue with `$("body").css("overflow","hidden");` is that it makes the main scrollbars disappearing. I guess not waht an user would expect as behaviour

Comment: I fixed the "blink" in my answer. See below. :) enjoy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For make that `.header` must be in position `absolute`.

I have add a variable `topT` for check if is top or not and a timer for no scrolling page.

Please try:

CodePen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXOdwN

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
  <h1>hello visitor</h1> 
</div>
<div class="subsection">
  <div class="subsection--inner">
    <h2>welcome</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In porttitor ipsum eu lacus commodo pulvinar. Donec nec facilisis augue. Nulla in magna iaculis, sagittis dolor vitae, scelerisque risus. Cras fermentum rhoncus nunc, vel gravida sapien tempor at.
      Aliquam rhoncus, metus ac egestas aliquam, augue augue vulputate dolor, id sodales lorem sem quis lectus. Etiam rhoncus neque ligula. Ut ornare nec diam non sodales. Vivamus venenatis congue tellus vitae elementum. Ut sed quam pretium, faucibus
      nulla id, ultrices mi. Suspendisse eleifend posuere augue a vulputate. Praesent nec nisl nisl. Ut molestie convallis ligula, eget commodo nisi cursus sit amet. Maecenas mollis enim in odio fermentum, ac commodo nibh tincidunt. Aliquam molestie ex
      in nunc ornare faucibus. Pellentesque vel massa condimentum, dictum purus id, congue velit. Cras nec eleifend ipsum, eget lobortis tellus. Pellentesque sed tellus id sem consectetur viverra eget vel magna. Ut pretium ex nec malesuada laoreet. Quisque
      et malesuada eros, non dignissim diam. Integer in semper erat, sit amet hendrerit ipsum. Duis volutpat ac libero non aliquam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aenean varius laoreet purus
      sit amet porta. Mauris congue, orci quis ultricies ornare, ligula tortor ornare urna, sed fringilla turpis nulla ac sem. Nam nisi odio, consectetur nec nunc in, luctus pretium tellus. Suspendisse in leo elementum, rhoncus risus ut, blandit metus.
      Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In viverra urna vel turpis hendrerit, sed tincidunt dui fringilla. Proin mattis nisl nec mauris consequat congue. Praesent gravida eget dolor nec fermentum. Proin
      finibus, magna elementum convallis viverra, leo nisi convallis magna, a condimentum nisl sem nec mauris. Sed ultricies lorem eu lectus tristique, sed ornare lorem auctor. Proin tincidunt enim dapibus nunc scelerisque, at consequat quam lobortis.
      Nunc ornare lectus sit amet leo pharetra, at faucibus magna sodales. Cras auctor lacus lorem, ac porta libero feugiat vitae. Mauris metus velit, aliquam sit amet nunc eu, efficitur fermentum dolor. Suspendisse sed sagittis turpis, nec faucibus massa.
      Fusce sagittis massa est, at sagittis est fermentum et. Curabitur egestas arcu eu neque elementum, sit amet sodales nibh viverra. Donec nec placerat nunc. Mauris non orci dapibus, porttitor leo quis, eleifend ante. Vivamus sed risus neque. Pellentesque
      eget laoreet ante. Maecenas sed vehicula purus. Nam at sapien quis tortor vulputate tempor. Cras dignissim, metus sodales facilisis bibendum, dui erat faucibus elit, vel varius nisl lectus sed ante. Pellentesque ut magna consectetur est tempus vestibulum.
      Maecenas fermentum metus nec accumsan volutpat. Mauris in viverra magna. Sed ante erat, blandit id fringilla eget, rhoncus at odio. Curabitur in metus nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Cras hendrerit augue massa, ullamcorper eleifend sapien ornare vel.</p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In porttitor ipsum eu lacus commodo pulvinar. Donec nec facilisis augue. Nulla in magna iaculis, sagittis dolor vitae, scelerisque risus. Cras fermentum rhoncus nunc, vel gravida sapien tempor at.
      Aliquam rhoncus, metus ac egestas aliquam, augue augue vulputate dolor, id sodales lorem sem quis lectus. Etiam rhoncus neque ligula. Ut ornare nec diam non sodales. Vivamus venenatis congue tellus vitae elementum. Ut sed quam pretium, faucibus
      nulla id, ultrices mi. Suspendisse eleifend posuere augue a vulputate. Praesent nec nisl nisl. Ut molestie convallis ligula, eget commodo nisi cursus sit amet. Maecenas mollis enim in odio fermentum, ac commodo nibh tincidunt. Aliquam molestie ex
      in nunc ornare faucibus. Pellentesque vel massa condimentum, dictum purus id, congue velit. Cras nec eleifend ipsum, eget lobortis tellus. Pellentesque sed tellus id sem consectetur viverra eget vel magna. Ut pretium ex nec malesuada laoreet. Quisque
      et malesuada eros, non dignissim diam. Integer in semper erat, sit amet hendrerit ipsum. Duis volutpat ac libero non aliquam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aenean varius laoreet purus
      sit amet porta. Mauris congue, orci quis ultricies ornare, ligula tortor ornare urna, sed fringilla turpis nulla ac sem. Nam nisi odio, consectetur nec nunc in, luctus pretium tellus. Suspendisse in leo elementum, rhoncus risus ut, blandit metus.
      Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In viverra urna vel turpis hendrerit, sed tincidunt dui fringilla. Proin mattis nisl nec mauris consequat congue. Praesent gravida eget dolor nec fermentum. Proin
      finibus, magna elementum convallis viverra, leo nisi convallis magna, a condimentum nisl sem nec mauris. Sed ultricies lorem eu lectus tristique, sed ornare lorem auctor. Proin tincidunt enim dapibus nunc scelerisque, at consequat quam lobortis.
      Nunc ornare lectus sit amet leo pharetra, at faucibus magna sodales. Cras auctor lacus lorem, ac porta libero feugiat vitae. Mauris metus velit, aliquam sit amet nunc eu, efficitur fermentum dolor. Suspendisse sed sagittis turpis, nec faucibus massa.
      Fusce sagittis massa est, at sagittis est fermentum et. Curabitur egestas arcu eu neque elementum, sit amet sodales nibh viverra. Donec nec placerat nunc. Mauris non orci dapibus, porttitor leo quis, eleifend ante. Vivamus sed risus neque. Pellentesque
      eget laoreet ante. Maecenas sed vehicula purus. Nam at sapien quis tortor vulputate tempor. Cras dignissim, metus sodales facilisis bibendum, dui erat faucibus elit, vel varius nisl lectus sed ante. Pellentesque ut magna consectetur est tempus vestibulum.
      Maecenas fermentum metus nec accumsan volutpat. Mauris in viverra magna. Sed ante erat, blandit id fringilla eget, rhoncus at odio. Curabitur in metus nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Cras hendrerit augue massa, ullamcorper eleifend sapien ornare vel.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
.header {
 background:url("http://tympanus.net/Development/ArticleIntroEffects/img/7.jpg") center center no-repeat; 
  background-size:cover;
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transform:translateY(0);
  transition:1s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1) .2s;
  opacity:1;
  &.header--scrolled {
    transform:translateY(-100%);
    opacity:0;
    transition:1s ease-in;
  }

  h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    text-align: center;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.subsection {
  transition:.6s ease-out;
  opacity:0;
  transform:translateY(20px);

    &.header--scrolled {
    opacity:1;
    transition:1s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) .6s;
      transform:translateY(0);
      }
}
.subsection--inner {
  max-width:800px;
  padding:0 20px 60px 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

**JQUERY**

```
(function($, sr) {
  var debounce = function(func, threshold, execAsap) {
      var timeout;

      return function debounced() {
        var obj = this,
          args = arguments;

        function delayed() {
          if (!execAsap)
            func.apply(obj, args);
          timeout = null;
        };

        if (timeout)
          clearTimeout(timeout);
        else if (execAsap)
          func.apply(obj, args);

        timeout = setTimeout(delayed, threshold || 100);
      };
    }
    // smartresize 
  jQuery.fn[sr] = function(fn) {
    return fn ? this.bind('resize', debounce(fn)) : this.trigger(sr);
  };

})(jQuery, 'smartresize');


function intro() {
  var topT = 0;
  t = setInterval(function(){
    if(topT==0){
      window.scrollTo( 0, 0 );
    }
  },20)
  var wh = window.innerHeight;
  $(".header").css("height", wh);
  $(".subsection").css("padding-top", (wh / 3 * 2));

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scroll == 0 && topT==0){
      var header = $(".header");
      var subsection = $(".subsection");
      header.addClass("header--scrolled");
      subsection.addClass("header--scrolled");

      header.one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',
        function(e) {
            topT=1;
        });
    }else if(scroll == 0 && topT==1){
      $(".subsection").removeClass("header--scrolled");
      $(".header").removeClass("header--scrolled");
      topT=0;
    }
  });
};
intro();

$(window).smartresize(function() {
  intro();

});
```

Comment: great!! looks like it's working. there's a little *blink* on first scroll though, what can that be?

Comment: i dont see this blink in codepen. Have you a web page for i can check that?

Comment: i do see it in codepen, looks like it scrolls down a bit, then snaps back on top, and then the animation starts. it's probably the snapping back to top that creates that effect. if you want to look at that that would be cool, else don't worry :) you helped me loads already ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Getting rid of the hitch at the beginning**

The CSS `position` attribute on the `intro` div needs to be set to `fixed`

Here's my example: http://codepen.io/internationalhouseofdonald/pen/aWWNqV

This script stops the user from scrolling when the page loads and then enables scrolling after 1000 milliseconds.

## JavaScript

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        disableScroll();
    });

    setTimeout(function(){ enableScroll() }, 1000);

// left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40,
// spacebar: 32, pageup: 33, pagedown: 34, end: 35, home: 36

var keys = {37: 1, 38: 1, 39: 1, 40: 1};

function preventDefault(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.preventDefault)
      e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = false;  
}

function preventDefaultForScrollKeys(e) {
    if (keys[e.keyCode]) {
        preventDefault(e);
        return false;
    }
}

function disableScroll() {
  if (window.addEventListener) // older FF
      window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
  window.onwheel = preventDefault; // modern standard
  window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = preventDefault; // older browsers, IE
  window.ontouchmove  = preventDefault; // mobile
  document.onkeydown  = preventDefaultForScrollKeys;
}

function enableScroll() {
    if (window.removeEventListener)
        window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = null; 
    window.onwheel = null; 
    window.ontouchmove = null;  
    document.onkeydown = null;  
}
```

The only downside to this design is that if the user grabs the scrollbar (like I would on my Surface with my Surface Pen), the page would still scroll.